# Can't use external jar in VS Code

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I have created spring-boot project in VS Code with maven. I am going to use `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` to connect to `oracle` database. In Intellij Idea,
with right click on the jar I used to click `add as library` and it was done.

In visual studio code I have added path to `ojdbc8.jar` in `.classpath` as shown in [this](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/346) github issue, But I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` again.

[image]

Comment: [add local jar files to maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project) - this might help

Comment: @venkat, it helped me. it means that pom.xml should be modified too..

Comment: @D F - Yes, in a maven project all the dependencies are handled by pom.xml, we can use either the maven repositories to download the dependencies or add it from an external folder. If my comments helped you, can you please up vote it?

Comment: You can also write an answer and I will mark it as correct one...

Comment: Posted the answer

Comment: @venkat, I used the second answer in the linked post but this work too..

Comment: Both should work and thanks- @D F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a maven project, all the dependencies are handled by pom.xml. We can use either maven repositories to download the dependencies or you can add it from your local directory. The following can be done install jar to local maven repository.

```
 mvn install:install-file \
-Dfile=<path-to-file> \
-DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
-Dversion=<version> \
-Dpackaging=<packaging> \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

Reference - http://maven.apache.org/general.html#importing-jars